# Code design for program in Scheme dealing with user input

Tags: functional-programming, architecture, scheme, lisp

I'm trying to code small program, ancient game [Hamurabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamurabi_(video_game)) in Scheme (guile to be exact). I want to learn about preferred approach to "design" of such program, extensively dealing with user input. E.g. using loops, mutable or immutable variables etc.

I have some working variants which I don't like well. I believe I miss some better approach. Below are details. **Sorry for long explanations.**

The game itself is simple "economics" simulation - we have 3 values, for population of our kingdom, land area and amount of grain (also serving as currency). Player rules for several years, choosing each year consecutively:

- how many land to buy or sell for grain
- then how many grain to use for feeding people
- at last how many grain to use for sowing

So we have outer loop with iterations representing years. Inside we have three steps. First changes amounts of area and grain. Second
changes amounts of grain and population. Third is changing amount of grain (with respect to available land and people to tend fields). The fourth step (without user input) determines how many new crops we gathered and what was eaten by rats (i.e. increases amount of grain).

This can easily be done with using global variables and `(set! ...)` forms. However I wonder to find way to code this in more "functional style". It seems I then need to use several mutually recursive (tail-optimized) functions to represent steps. And pass changed values as parameters each time. [Here is gist with this approach implemented with only step of buying/selling land](https://gist.github.com/RodionGork/b8b81aaf1739ca611f87b40bf7705705). And it works like this:

```
You have 100 people, 700 acres of land and 9600 bushels of grain.
Land trades at 24 bushels of grain for acre
How many acres to buy? -100
You have 100 people, 600 acres of land and 12000 bushels of grain.
Land trades at 21 bushels of grain for acre
How many acres to buy? 200
```

It is not very convenient as there would be many small functions and most of them need all variables even though some are passed through. And besides the `pop`, `area` and `grain` we need some accumulators (e.g. total people died of starvation).

So I created two functions to maintain immutable key-value structure like

```
(list (cons 'pop 100) (cons 'area 1000) (cons 'grain 2800))
```

And use them as `state` passed to every function. `prop-get` fetches value by key from the state while `prop-set` returns modified copy (I suspect there is some similar structure already implemented in library).

```
(load "props.scm")

(define (one-year state)
    (map display
        (list "You have "
            (prop-get state 'pop) " people, "
            (prop-get state 'area) " acres of land and "
            (prop-get state 'grain) " bushels of grain."))
    (newline)
    (let ((state-upd (buy-land state)))
        (step-2 state-upd)))

(define (buy-land state)
    (let ((price (+ (random 10) 17))
            (area (prop-get state 'area))
            (grain (prop-get state 'grain)))
        (map display
            (list "Land trades at " price " bushels of grain for acre"))
        (newline)
        (display "How many acres to buy? ")
        (let ((b (read)))
            (prop-set (prop-set state 'area (+ area b)) 'grain (- grain (* price b))))))
```

[Please here is the complete code in another gist](https://gist.github.com/RodionGork/7be48971959809d1feea55601c3312a7).

This is somewhat better but still the complete code is a bit verbose with all those prop-gets, lets and mutual recursion.

What other options could be here? I think there is "intermediate" solution between mutable global variables and immutables with tail recursion - like using named let for outer loop and some mutable structure to hold the state in a local variable. But I feel like I may be miss something more simple and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a purely functionnal approach, you need to pass a state variable from one place to another.
We can use an association list to store elements, and since in Hammurabi the game finishes in 10 steps, we can easily use the state variable as a journal, a log of all events that happened in the game.

Association lists have the property that mappings can occur multiple times, but only the first match is returned.
So basically, if the state is `((population . 100) (population . 30))`, then it means the current population is 100, and at the previous turn it was 30. We store all values in slots, which means we can perfom statistics on the resulting game as much as we want.

For exemple, the initial state is:

```
(define initial-state '((population . 100)
                        (acres . 1000)
                        (grain . 3000)
                        (year . 0)))
```

We can hide the specific implementation details behind auxiliary accessor functions:

```
(define (value state slot)
  (cdr (assoc slot state)))
```

And also, we can use a useful syntax to add multiple elements at once in a state:

```
 (define (extend0 state key/values)
   (if (null? key/values)
       state
       (let ((key (car key/values))
             (val (cadr key/values))
             (tail (cddr key/values)))
         (extend0 (acons key val state) tail))))

 (define (extend state . key/values)
   (extend0 state key/values))
```

So, for example, you can do:

```
(extend initial-state 'grain 1000 'population 200)
$1 = ((population . 200) (grain . 1000) (population . 100) (acres . 1000) (grain . 3000) (year . 0))
```

We can also define accessors for common slots:

```
(define (getter slot)
  (lambda (state)
    (value state slot)))

(define (setter slot)
  (lambda (state value)
    (acons slot value state)))

(define population (getter 'population))
(define set-population (setter 'population))

(define acres (getter 'acres))
(define set-acres (setter 'acres))

(define grain (getter 'grain))
(define set-grain (setter 'grain))

(define price (getter 'price))
(define set-price (setter 'price))

(define year (getter 'year))
(define set-year (setter 'year))
```

You could also shorten the above with a macro. The approach here consists in designing little auxiliary functions along the way, to ensure that the actual code we write is as expressive as we want it to be.

Also, test often and in isolation, which is easier to do when no internal state is involved.

Define also a smart object printer:

```
(define (echo items state)
  (if (list? items)
      (map (lambda (u)
             (cond
              ((null? u) (newline))
              ((symbol? u) (display (value state u)))
              ((procedure? u) (display (u)))
              (else (display u))))
           items)
      (begin (display items) (newline)))
  state)
```

... and a generic prompt:

```
(define (prompt state message tester setter)
  (echo message state)
  (let ((value (read)))
    (if (tester value)
        (setter state value)
        (prompt state message tester setter))))
```

Once all the vocabulary is in place, here is how you could write `buy-land`:

```
(define (buy-land state)
  (let ((max-acres (floor/ (grain state) (price state))))
    (if (zero? max-acres)
        (echo "You cannot buy any acre." state)
        (prompt state
                `("Land trades at " price " bushels of grain for acre." ()
                  "You have " grain " bushel(s) of grain." ()
                  "How many acres to buy (0-" ,max-acres ")? ")
                (lambda (v) (and (integer? v) (<= 0 v max-acres)))
                (lambda (state buy)
                  (extend state
                          'buy buy
                          'acres (+ (acres state) buy)
                          'grain (- (grain state)
                                    (* buy (price state)))))))))
```

You can split functions into little ones that do less things, but that compose better:

```
(define (random-events state)
  (let ((starve (random 20)))
    (extend state
            'starve starve
            'price (+ 17 (random 10))
            'population (max 0 (- (population state) starve)))))

(define (game-step state)
  (if (= (year state) 10)
      (end-game state)
      (let ((state (set-year state (+ 1 (year state)))))
        (display-new-year-text state)
        (let ((state (random-events state)))
          (game-step (buy-land state))))))

(define hammurabi
  (game-step initial-state))
```